# Ansible Kubernetes Job arg inject random string

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, yaml

I am thinking about creating a Kubernetes job in Ansible with random string (password) generated on the fly and injected to the `args`/`command` line. However I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve will work as the below Jinja template itself already imports data from the values YAML file.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: {{ deployment.namespace }} <- taken from the values YAML
  name: create-secret
  labels:
    app: test
    app.kubernetes.io/name: create-secret
    app.kubernetes.io/component: test
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: test
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: test
  annotations:
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: {{ deployment.namespace }} <- taken from the values YAML
      name: create-secret
      labels:
        app: test
        app.kubernetes.io/name: create-secret
        app.kubernetes.io/component: test
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: test
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: test
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: create-secret
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["-c", "somecommand create --secret {{ lookup('community.general.random_string', min_lower=1, min_upper=1, min_special=1, min_numeric=1, length=15) }} --name 'test'"]
        image: {{ registry.host }}/{{ images.docker.image.name }}:{{ images.docker.image.tag }} <- taken from the values YAML
```

Comment: Please don't ask if it will work: **try it** yourself, make an honest attempt to fix the problems you face if you have any and ask a question about an actual issue with details of what is the exact result / error you get compared to the expected one and provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It'll work fine, but (as you pointed out) due to golang/helm using the same template characters as jinja2 `{{`, you'll need to take one of two approaches: either wrap every golang set of mustaches in `{{ "{{" }}` in order for *jinja2* to emit the *text* `{{` in the resulting file, or [change the jinja2 template delimiters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#parameter-variable_start_string) to something other than `{{`

### example 1

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: {{ "{{" }} deployment.namespace {{ "}}" }}
  name: create-secret
...
      containers:
      - name: create-secret
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["-c", "somecommand create --secret {{ lookup('community.general.random_string', min_lower=1, min_upper=1, min_special=1, min_numeric=1, length=15) }} --name 'test'"]
        image: {{ "{{" }} registry.host {{ "}}" }}/{{ "{{" }} images.docker.image.name {{ "}}:{{" }} images.docker.image.tag {{ "}}" }} <- taken from the values YAML
```

Although you'll also likely want to use `| quote` for that `random_string` since in my local example, it produce a password of `` 2-b19e2k@HUF=k` `` and that ` will be interpreted by the `sh -c` leading to an error

### example 2

```yaml
# my-job.yml.j2
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: {{ deployment.namespace }} <- taken from the values YAML
  name: create-secret
...
      containers:
      - name: create-secret
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["-c", "somecommand create --secret [% lookup('community.general.random_string', min_lower=1, min_upper=1, min_special=1, min_numeric=1, length=15) %] --name 'test'"]
        image: {{ registry.host }}/{{ images.docker.image.name }}:{{ images.docker.image.tag }} <- taken from the values YAML
```

```yaml
- template:
    src: my-job.yml.j2
    dest: my-job.yml
    variable_start_string: '[%'
    variable_end_string: '%]'
```